# Breaking each closure vs. returning from the method

Tags: groovy

The first `return` in the following method does not end the method, but instead breaks out of the loop

```
boolean isAnyColorRed() {
  colors.each { 
    if (it.type == "red")
       return true // does not end the method but instead breaks the loop.
  }
  return false
}
```

What is a workaround? This?

```
boolean isAnyColorRed() {
  boolean foundRed = false
  colors.each { 
    if (it.type == "red") {
        foundRed = true
        return //break the loop
    } 
  }
  if (foundRed)
    return true
  else
    return false
}
```

Comment: use `each` only for side effects and you will use it quite rarely in your codebase.

Answer (score 0):

A much groovier way to do this:

```
colors.any { it.type == 'red' }
```

That will return `true` or `false`, so you can use it in an `if` expression...